# I cannot create Web Application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a webapplication in VS 2019. but even in creating stage, I select Web Application, I find it Web Control Library.

even when I go to project properties, I do not see **Web Application** listed..

I missing some functions that work on Web Application like `Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString`

any one can give a suggestion, how to convert Web Control to Web Project ?

[image]

Comment: Run the VS installer and make sure that you have the *ASP.NET and web development* workload installed. If you want to target .NET Core rather than .NET Framework, make sure that you have the *.NET Core cross-platform development* workload installed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to make a new project, and something like this appears, and you choose Web from the type of project ropdown, do you see what you want? Do you see an option to install the template you're looking for if you don't have it installed currently?

[image]

It sounds like you're hoping to create a project for which the relevant template is not installed on your computer..

Comment: Thanks.. What i see is exactly what is in the pic... It looks that i need ASP. NET website core

Comment: THis was done from a computer that only ever does windows apps dev, so it doesn't really have anything web related installed